# PhalconPHP - How to display 500 error to users

Tags: php, error-handling, phalcon

How to **display 500 error with PhalconPHP** to users?

I use this code to display 404 error (display **error404.volt** view) and 500 error (display **error500.volt** view).
The 404 error page display as expected but not the 500 error page.

```
$di->set('dispatcher', function() {
    //Create/Get an EventManager
    $eventsManager = new \Phalcon\Events\Manager();
    //Attach a listener
    $eventsManager->attach("dispatch:beforeException", function($event, $dispatcher, $exception) {
        //Handle 404 exceptions
        if ($exception instanceof \Phalcon\Mvc\Dispatcher\Exception) {
            $dispatcher->forward(array(
                    'controller' => 'index',
                    'action' => 'error404'
            ));
            return false;
        }
        //Handle other exceptions
        $dispatcher->forward(array(
                'controller' => 'index',
                'action' => 'error500'
        ));
        return false;
    });
    $dispatcher = new \Phalcon\Mvc\Dispatcher();
    //Bind the EventsManager to the dispatcher
    $dispatcher->setEventsManager($eventsManager);
    return $dispatcher;
}, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by setting the status of the request in the forwarded controller's action. In your case indexController::error500Action()

```
$this->response->setStatusCode(500, "Internal Server Error");
```

Comment: I did and it still does not show error in the browser.

Comment: then try using the php function header("HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error");

Comment: please see my updated question, I'd like to display view "error500" to users when the Internal Server Error happens, using function header currently display nothing in the browser.

Comment: sorry for that. i see you are forwarding the request to error500Action in indexController. This being said you need to create the controller and the action for it. I highly recommend you to read the documentation for phalcon and check out the invo site example: http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/index.html

Comment: I have created the controller "IndexController.php" and action "public function error500Action(){}" but still nothing is displayed.

Comment: did you also create the views for it?

Comment: Yes, I have created a view for it.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following in **public/index.php**
An empty **error404Action** function is needed in **Controllers/IndexController.php**
along with a **views/index/error404.phtml** file where i create my custom error page

```
    try
    {
        //load phalcon
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        $errorCode = $e->getCode();
        if($errorCode === 2 OR $errorCode === 5)
        {
            $response = new \Phalcon\Http\Response();
            $response->redirect('index/error404');
            $response->send();
            //return;
        }

        // put here code for managing your case

    }
```